# Automatically open attribute table after ModelBuilder is complete?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-table

I know there is a setting to add the finished product to the map after model builder is done.

Is there a setting to automatically open up the attribute table after as well?

Answer (score 4):

Not that I'm aware of in ModelBuilder as a setting.  The only way I can see calling that action would be calling a python script at the end of the model that makes the .net arcobject call to open said layer/table.

Comment: Just off the top of your head, would that be a simple script to create?

Comment: It depends on your experience writing python scripts and how to make .net calls from them.  This site has some q/a on calling .net/arcobjects from python script.

Comment: No, it's not easy but would be the only way to do what you're after, you will probably need to download some modules. Have a read of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python on how to get started and an answer I gave about reading the ArcObjects help document http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129456/guidelines-for-using-arcobjects-from-python/150711#150711

Answer (score 0):

If you have ArcGIS Pro, you should considering leveraging Tasks to automate the steps in your workflow. You can make opening the attribute table automatic after the Model runs and more. See https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/tasks/whatistask.htm