# ArcMap add-in to make connection and load the database on VB.NET

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, add-in, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm new at Arcobjects programming. Currently I'm trying to make an ArcMap Add-in which can connect and load a database into ArcMap.
I have found samples on the Esri website, but it seems not to be working for me.

Here's the code:

```
' For example, path = "C:\myData\mypGDB.mdb".'

Public Function AccessWorkspaceFromPath(ByVal Path As String) As IWorkspace 

  Dim workspaceFactory As IWorkspaceFactory = New AccessWorkspaceFactoryClass()
  Return workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(Path, 0)

End Function
```

What seems to be the problem is the Microsoft Visual Studio can't recognize the class `AccessWorkspaceFactoryClass()`.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Many things can go wrong when porgramming with ArcObjects. I would certainly recommend doing a proper training if you want to do this. That said, did you add a reference to ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB to your VS project?

Comment: Have you referenced and imported DataSourcesGDB? You should have a line **Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB** as the AccessWorkspaceFactory http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001m00000001000000 is in the DataSourcesGDB reference (note the line on the link that says ArcObjects Library Reference (DataSourcesGDB) ) have a quick read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129456/guidelines-for-using-arcobjects-from-python/150711#150711 to understand how to use the ArcObjects help to discern which references to import.